# Instantiating an object using another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this script to create an npc character that will run around a game area at randm to set game points and i have created one in my game whihc works fine however when i try to use a script to create it the npc losses all way points in the  List _patrolPoints and it just creates cubes that sit there and dont move due to not having any way points

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class navmesh : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    bool _patrolWaiting;
    [SerializeField]
    float _totalWaitTime = 3f;
    [SerializeField]
    float _switchProbability = 0.2f;
    [SerializeField]
    List<Waypoint> _patrolPoints;

    NavMeshAgent _navMeshAgent;
    int _currentPatrolIndex;
    bool _traveling;
    bool _waiting;
    bool _patrolFoward;
    float _waitTimer;

    void Start() {
        _navMeshAgent = this.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        _currentPatrolIndex = 0;
        SetDestination();
    }

    void Update() {
        _currentPatrolIndex = 0;
        SetDestination();
        if (_traveling && _navMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= 1.0f) {
            _traveling = false;
            if (_patrolWaiting) {
                _waiting = true;
                _waitTimer = 0f;
            }
            else {
                ChangePatrolPoint();
                SetDestination();
            }
        }
        if (_waiting) {
            _waitTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (_waitTimer >= _totalWaitTime) {
                _waiting = false;
                ChangePatrolPoint();
                SetDestination();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetDestination() {
        if (_patrolPoints != null) {
            Vector3 targetVector = _patrolPoints[_currentPatrolIndex].transform.position;
            _navMeshAgent.SetDestination(targetVector);
            _traveling = true;
        }
    }

    private void ChangePatrolPoint() {
        if (UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f) <= _switchProbability) {
            _patrolFoward = !_patrolFoward;
        }
        if (_patrolFoward) {
            _currentPatrolIndex = (_currentPatrolIndex + 1) % _patrolPoints.Count;
        }
        else {
            if (--_currentPatrolIndex < 0) {
                _currentPatrolIndex = _patrolPoints.Count - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NPCspawn : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject NPC;
    public Transform NPCspawn1;
    public float SpawnRate;
    private float SpawnFire;

    void Update() {
        if (SpawnFire < 20 && Time.time > SpawnFire) {
            SpawnFire = Time.time + SpawnRate;
            Instantiate(NPC, NPCspawn1.position, NPCspawn1.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting `_patrolPoints` in the Unity Editor and not in the class?

Comment: @Thatalent i am setting it in the Editor (i think)

Comment: Setting the values in the Editor and not in code stops you from coping the values over when you're making a new instant. You want to make a prefab or set it in code. I'll post an answer with an example of each later

Answer (score 0):

Is the object you are using for the `NPC` property a prefab?  If so, it should retain all the values you have set for that prefab in the editor.

However, if your `_patrolpoints` aren't part of the prefab (ie. `NPC` is an in-scene object that you have configured in the editor), then you will need to apply those `_patrolpoints` to each instantiated copy manually.

Your code doesn't show where your `_patrolpoints` are being set, but for the snippet below, let's assume `_patrolpoints` is a public array field of navmesh (instead of a private List),

```
void Update() 
{
    if (SpawnFire < 20 && Time.time > SpawnFire) {
        SpawnFire = Time.time + SpawnRate;
        GameObject copy = Instantiate(NPC, NPCspawn1.position, NPCspawn1.rotation);
        navmesh nm = copy.GetComponent<navmesh>();
        nm._patrolpoints = master_array_of_patrol_points;
    }
}
```